# How do I enable "clickable" logs to the "Messages" window in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In intellij I have a large project, some of it uses complex external scripts to generate and format code, build resources, compile java code etc.  These scripts are spawned from an ant target and the output shows up in the "Messages" window in intellij.

Error messages from the java compiler and other processes are logged to this window preceded by a blue (i) and most contain the path to the source file, line number etc.

UNLIKE the internal java compiler output window these messages ARE NOT clickable so as to allow you to navigate to the file and line number in the project/modules.

Is there any way to enable, and how does one format items logged to the "Messages" window containing the path to the file and the line number so as to make the entries clickable for navigation ??

Comment: Messages window uses the tree view and has special API to display links. See com.intellij.util.ui.ErrorTreeView and com.intellij.ide.errorTreeView.NewErrorTreeViewPanel.

Comment: seems way way complicated - other IDEs ( like microsoft and eclipse ) just use a recognizable log format like "path:(line#) [message]"  which can easily be put in the output loe formatter of the process making the log entries.

Comment: Ant messages view has 2 modes: tree and text. In the tree view it gets info from Ant regarding what is the message (error, warning, text, whether it has links to files, etc). In the text mode IDE can navigate to the files using the Java stacktrace format.

Comment: Thanks - so how does one select the "text view" for ant build output? and make it sticky for the project?

In my case the log text is all from the stdout/stderr of the spawned subprocesses.

Comment: I found the button to toggle the view - once I test it will put it in as an answer unless you want to post it :)